# request body for static inner class of xml root element

Tags: spring-mvc, jaxb2

I'm trying to get an object parsed from XML (request body). My controller method's header is

```
public ModelAndView differentTypeOfIds(@RequestBody DiffIdsRequest.DescBatch body){
```

where DescBatch is static inner class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { 
    "descBatch"
})  
@XmlRootElement(name = "diffIdsRequest")
public class DiffIdsRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "desc-batch", required = true)
    protected DiffIdsRequest.DescBatch descBatch;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { 
        "descItem"
    })  
    public static class DescBatch {
```

A snippet of servlet configuration

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="eu.eudml.restModel.DiffIdsRequest$DescBatch" />
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

In logs I can see line

```
2012-07-31 17:34:11,604   [] [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  o.s.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller - Creating JAXBContext with clas    ses to be bound [class eu.eudml.restModel.DiffIdsRequest$DescBatch]
```

It seems to be ok, but when I'm sending some data (xml without any namespaces) method differentTypeIds isn't called. ModelAndView is null (logs).

Are there any problems with inner class or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be missing `@XmlRootElement` or `@XmlType` on `DescBatch`. Also, you have to ensure that an Accept header of `application/xml` is sent as part of the request.

Comment: I can't unmarshall any static classes nested inside class being xmlRootElement?

Comment: Yes, but a nested static class behaves like a totally independent class, just that it is nested inside another classes body - so it will also need to have a `@XmlRootElement` annotation for the `@RequestBody` to be able to take effect.